# Unable to list memberships for groups which are collaborators through the box API

Tags: box-api

I'm getting an error trying to list membership of Groups which are collaborators on a folder. Here's a sample folder collaborators request -

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/1531887577/collaborations -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

And the response -

```
{
   "total_count":6,
   "entries":[
      {
         "type":"collaboration",
         "id":"25306820",
         "created_by":null,
         "created_at":"2012-09-06T09:48:20-07:00",
         "modified_at":"2013-10-19T09:37:14-07:00",
         "expires_at":null,
         "status":"accepted",
         "accessible_by":{
            "type":"user",
            "id":"184577095",
            "name":"Clayton C",
            "login":"clayc@xxxxxxx.com"
         },
         "role":"editor",
         "acknowledged_at":"2012-09-06T09:48:20-07:00",
         "item":{
            "type":"folder",
            "id":"379625555",
            "sequence_id":"7",
            "etag":"7",
            "name":"Business"
         }
      },
      .... more users ....,
      {
         "type":"collaboration",
         "id":"39809829",
         "created_by":null,
         "created_at":"2013-05-27T09:20:32-07:00",
         "modified_at":"2013-10-23T04:20:34-07:00",
         "expires_at":null,
         "status":"accepted",
         "accessible_by":{
            "type":"group",
            "id":"120995",
            "name":"IT"
         },
         "role":"editor",
         "acknowledged_at":"2013-05-27T09:20:32-07:00",
         "item":{
            "type":"folder",
            "id":"379625555",
            "sequence_id":"7",
            "etag":"7",
            "name":"NewBusiness"
         }
      },
      .... more groups ....,
   ]
}
```

Note group "IT" with ID "120995" in the list of collaborators. Now I request membership for the group

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/groups/120995/memberships -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

And I get this weird error response.

```
{
   "type":"error",
   "status":404,
   "code":"not_found",
   "context_info":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "reason":"invalid_parameter",
            "name":"group_tag",
            "message":"Invalid value 'g_120995'. 'group_tag' with value 'g_120995' not found"
         }
      ]
   },
   "help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
   "message":"Not Found",
   "request_id":"184613996752e9780c42c3f"
}
```

Has anyone seen similar behavior and found a solution?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the /groups/<id>/memberships endpoint around groups/memberships permissions.   You should either be getting some kind of "permission denied" if your enterprise admin has turned off visibility of the users in collabs, or you should get the list of members in the group.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say: "Note this is only available to group admins."